# Regex PHP - Validation of email address

Tags: php, regex, validation

```
function validateemail($email) {
$v = "/[a-zA-Z0-9_-.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]+/";

return (bool)preg_match($v, $email);
}
// check e-mail address, to see if it's a valid phone number
if ($validateemail($email)) {
$error = true;
echo 'Invalid phone number!';
}
```

I'm trying to check if an e-mail address is valid by the function `validateemail`, if it's an invalid phone number a message is displayed and `$error` is set to true. However I can't seem to get this code to work, there are no syntax errors as far as I know. Any advice would be appreciated.

BTW - I know there are other ways to validate e-mail addresses, this is for a college project and for that purpose we have to use regex.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For future readers who aren't doing this for a college project, please use [`filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php).

Comment: Also found my answer on http://emailregex.com

Comment: Please note that all the regexes on emailregex.com do different things.  The one under "Python" `r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)"` is entirely different than the one labeled "Javascript" `/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have `-` not in the final position inside the first `[a-zA-Z0-9_-.+]` group.

Try

`[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]+`

Have a look at this [example](https://regex101.com/r/aG8fB6/2).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dash as it can also be used to indicate a character range.

```
function validateemail($email) {
  $v = "/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]+/";
  return (bool)preg_match($v, $email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check if it is a valide e-mail or not, I'd suggest  filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, e.g.:

```
<?php
$email = "john.doe@example.com";

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
?>
```

Source: www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp